# Hindley-Milner type of a function that takes itself as an argument

Tags: haskell, hindley-milner

Suppose you had a function f that would be used as follows:

```
(f f (x-1))
```

What can you deduce about the type of f?

It seems to be recursive, ie, f :: (ftype) -> int -> int.

Comment: Right, I don’t think it’s possible for that expression to be valid in current Haskell.

Comment: @Ry why not? Looks valid to me.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Unless `f` is polymorphic and some type arguments are being implicitly added by the compiler, you can't apply `f` to itself and have the expression to be typed. You need something like a recursive type to wrap `f` with, say a `newtype`. Otherwise you get `f :: T -> U` and `f f` triggers `T ~ T -> U` which is rejected since unification fails in the "occurs check" step, since it would produce an infinite type. (Again, polymorphic functions like `f = id` can make `f f` to be typed since each `f` is actually a different instantiation.)

Comment: @chi - fair point, and I think for some reason I misread the expression as being f (f (x - 1)) which is of course very different. But even as written, as you yourself point out, it works for certain polymorphic functions `f`, so I would still question the statement that "it’s (not) possible for that expression to be valid in current Haskell".

Answer (score 3):

If an argument to a function is that function itself, then the type would have to be recursive and infinite in a way that's illegal in Haskell. There's one loophole, however: if the function is polymorphic in that argument, then it's fine (although probably not very useful as a function). Two examples of a valid `f` are `id` and `const id` (with either of them, `f f (x-1)` would just evaluate to `x-1`).

Comment: I think the "not very useful" bit might be decently debatable. Consider, for instance, `(.) (.)` or `fmap fmap`.

Comment: @David Fair point, but unless you have a **really** bizarre `Num` instance in play, I don't think any of those more useful functions would typecheck with `(x-1)` after them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you could apply a type-inference algorithm. Going about it informally, you can start by stating that `f :: a -> b -> c` because it takes two curried arguments. You can also infer the constraint `Num b` because of `x - 1`, so `f :: Num b => a -> b -> c`. Possibly more if you know what type `x` is. But that's about it.

For example, the function could be defined as `f g x = undefined`, in which case both of its arguments are discarded, and the return type does not unify with any of the input types. If `f` had a function body then you could infer a lot more.

Comment: I disagree with your claim about the `Num` constraint. For now, set aside the `f f` business and pretend you're just calling `f (x-1)`. Now, `f` could be `abs`, which has the `Num` constraint as you claim, or it could be `id`, which has no constraints at all, or it could be `take`, which only accepts an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

In your title, you ask about the "Hindley-Milner type" of `f`.  In usual parlance, the HM type of an expression is the principal (most general) type inferred for the expression through the formal HM type inference rules applied to a particular context.  So, `f` has no type without a context, and the expression `f f (x-1)` doesn't provide enough information about the context to type `f`.  Contexts can be given "at the start" or can develop through the use of lambda or `let` expressions.  The context that develops will determine if an HM type can be inferred for `f` and, if so, what that type is.

For example, the larger expression:

```
let f = \y -> y in \x -> f f (x-1)
```

can be typed in the empty context.  Without going through the details, it infers the type `forall a. a -> a` for `f` and the type `Integer -> Integer` for the whole expression, provided the `-` operator is `Integer` subtraction.  (The HM type system doesn't have a concept of type classes and constraints, like `Num`.)  So, here, the HM type for `f` is `forall a. a -> a`, and its use in the expression `f f (x-1)` doesn't really affect its type.  This is typical for expressions where `f` is introduced with a `let` expression.  For example, the larger expression:

```
let f = \y -> \z -> y in \x -> f f (x-1)
```

is also well typed.  The type inferred for `f` is `forall a b. a -> b -> a` (which is the obvious type for `\y -> \z -> y` and is not influenced by the rest of the expression).  The overall expression has type `forall a b. Integer -> a -> b -> a`.

In contrast, if `f` is introduced through a lambda expression, then things are different, and the expression `f f (x-1)` does influence the inferred type for `f`.  For example, the larger expression:

```
\f -> \x -> f f (x-1)
```

is ill-typed in HM and so doesn't infer a type for `f` or for the expression as a whole.  If the body of the double-lambda is changed, then different HM types can be inferred for `f` depending on the expression:

```
\f -> \x -> f (f x x) (x-1)   -- f :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
\f -> \x -> f x + f x         -- f :: forall a. a -> Integer
```

Sooooo...  to sum up, no type is inferred for `f` from the expression `f f (x-1)` alone because the context is insufficient.  In a context where `f` is introduced by a `let` expression, the type of `f` will be inferred strictly from the definition of `f`, and as long as the type is compatible with the expression `f f (x-1)`, type inference will succeed.  Conversely, in a context where `f` is introduced by a lambda expression, the expression `f f (x-1)` is ill-typed, so no type for `f` *can* be inferred.